# HVAC blows fuse when cooling kicks on

Tags: hvac, cooling, heat-pump

I have Rheem HVAC system that is about 12-4 years old (its an R22 unit).  Today it started blowing the fuse on the board when cooling kicks on.  The tstat shows a message that says power failure, then 1-2 seconds later, the fuse blows, and the whole thing turns off.

Some additional background:

- I can run the fan by itself without issue
- I have an ecobee4 smart thermostat. Today I swapped that out for a 'dumb' tstat to rule that out as the issue.  Same problem of blown fuses.
- About a month ago, I had the opposite problem. The fuse would blow when cooling would stop. I did all the troubleshooting I could Google, and ended up replacing the contactor in hopes that it was somehow shorting out when disconnecting.  I used the exact same model number contactor.  That seemed to fix it.  Until now...

Comment: "blowing the fuse on the board"... Do you mean your Distribution Board in the house, or is this a fuse on a printed circuit board? If it's the Distribution Board fuse, what size fuse, what size wire and what it the nameplate amp rating of the HVAC unit?

Comment: Could be a bad compressor.

Comment: @JRaef Its the tiny fuse (3A) on the PCB for the air handler.

Comment: @PhilFreedenberg -- since it's the control fuse, it's probably not the compressor.

Comment: @Zac -- do you have a multimeter?

Comment: Do you have any flashing LED’s or a group of them on?  The power failure and the fuse on the pcb is not A normal failure , is the compressor starting? A bad cap in the outside unit can make for hard starts and drop the supply voltage (if a inverter or vfd controlled this is a possibility) but I haven’t had a pcb fuse blow. The fan normally starts later when needed but could be controlled by the board not the contactor. But they are usually a bit larger.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Absolutely!

Comment: @EdBeal I don't see any flashing LEDs on the PCB.  The compressor starts and the whole thing runs for probably 3-5 seconds before dying.

Comment: Can you plug the red lead into the 10A jack, put the meter on AC amps, stick the meter probes where the fuse on the control board normally goes, and then try turning the AC on?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Any chance of damaging anything doing that, since there will no longer be a fuse in there to blow?

Comment: @Zac -- since it sounds like it's not a dead short, unlikely -- I'd make sure your meter's 10A range is fused, just in case, though

Comment: Is this a heat pump both heat and ac ? A reversing valve ? Since you said the fan was working (fan on outside unit? Was my thought until I reread fan working if the outside fan is not starting bad bearings ? )  , I would use caution with only a 10 amp inline amp meter yes there is a fuse in the meter to protect it but I have learned the hard way on that where a 1 amp fuse that was blowing had enough draw to pop the fuse in my fluke, I only use clamp meters unless doing calibrations that I know will not exceed the meter rating.  Is there a schematic for the system you could get a photo of?

Answer (score 1):

And I'm embarrassed to say that I've figured it out.  I thought I had checked all the wiring, but I missed a small section of exposed copper on the Y wire in the air handler.  Once I taped it up, the problem went away.

Thanks for the suggestions guys!